# Java apache PDFBox - Merge/stamp PDF overlay maintaining hyperlinks on both overlay and input PDF?

Tags: java, overlay, pdfbox

We are trying to implement Apache PDFBox Overlay. It works great, however, hyperlinks on the overlay page get lost.

In our case customers upload an overlay with often clickable details such as website and e-mailadres on it. The foreground PDF is an invoice, which also can contain hyperlinks for example to a product page.

Basically this is our code:

```
Overlay overlay = new Overlay();  //org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Overlay
overlay.setInputPDF(inputDoc); //PDDDocument inputDoc with hyperlinks
overlay.setDefaultOverlayPDF(overlayDoc); //PDDDocument overlayDoc with hyperlinks
```

Hyperlinks on the inputDoc still work, but hyperlinks on the overlayDoc don't. Is there another way (using PDFBox) to stamp the overlay PDF onto the inputDoc while keeping interactions such as hyperlinks?

[UPDATE]: Possible solution by posted below.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

It was quite a puzzle, suprisingly there is very little information to find on this matter. However, in the end it was pretty simple and I managed to get it working.

Basically what I did is (code example below):

- getAnnotations from the overlay PDF
- Used PDFBox overlay to overlay the input document with the overlay PDF
- Save the new, overlayed document
- Iterate through the new document pages: PDDocument.getPages()
- For every page in the new document, add the annotations from the overlay PDF
- That's all

Seems to work perfectly fine. The only thing I am not sure about is the part where I do annot.setPage(p) in the code below. Because everytime for the same annotation, I set a different page in the new document. It works, but I think it would be cleaner to create a new annotation instance and add the new annotation to the document. However, I have not figured out how to clone an annotation into a new instance. Ideas on this are welcome :)

Here's my (little bit stripped) code for anyone interested:

```
//instantiate PDDocuments for input PDF and overlay PDF
PDDocument PDDDoc_inputDoc = PDDocument.load(...);
PDDocument PDDDoc_overlay = PDDocument.load(...);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
ByteArrayOutputStream baos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 

//create PDFBox overlay
Overlay overlay = new Overlay();
overlay.setOverlayPosition(Overlay.Position.BACKGROUND);

//set inputDoc and overlayDoc PDFs
overlay.setInputPDF(PDDDoc_inputDoc);
overlay.setDefaultOverlayPDF(PDDDoc_overlay);

//execute overlay function
overlay.overlay(new HashMap<>()).save(baos);

//create new PDDocument from overlay
PDDocument PDD_newOverlaydDocument = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));

//for every page in the new (overlayed) document, add annotation from the source overlay PDF to the new PDF
PDPageTree pages = PDD_newOverlaydDocument.getPages();
for(PDPage p : pages){
    //get annotations from new document page
    List<PDAnnotation> pageAnnotations = p.getAnnotations();
                
    //add annotations from overlay page to the page
    for(PDAnnotation annot : overlayAnnotations) {
        annot.setPage(p);
        pageAnnotations.add(annot);
    }
}
        
//save new PDDDocument to outputstream or file and dow whatever you want with it        
PDD_newOverlaydDocument.save(...);

//close streams, cleanup, etc
....
```